# Stored Procedure with Multiple Queries and Parameters

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server and Java for this.

I'm intending to create a global procedure function, in which it will copy the records from 1 table to another table.

My current procedure:

```
create procedure callProcedure(@newTable varchar(100),
@tableField varchar(8000),
@table varchar(100))
as
begin
DELETE FROM @newTable;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT @newTable ON;

INSERT INTO @newTable(@tableField) SELECT @tableField FROM @table

SET IDENTITY_INSERT @newTable OFF;
end
```

When I execute the procedure.
This is the error that I received.

> SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near '@newTable'.

Sample final queries after being replaced with parameters

```
EXEC callProcedure(@newTable = 'EMPLOYEE_1', @tableField = 'ID, NAME, STATUS', @table = 'EMPLOYEE')
```

Please help with this.

Thank you.

```
EXEC callProcedure(@newTable = 'EMPLOYEE_1', @tableField = 'ID, NAME, STATUS', @table = 'EMPLOYEE')
```

will return the result.

Comment: SQL doesn't work like that, its a static language, you can't use variables in place of object names. You need dynamic SQL if you really must do it that way, but its not recommended.

Comment: so it can't be used as a global procedure ? since i will need to copy multiple tables

Comment: The *normal* design method with SQL is you create specific procedures for specific tables. As I said if you really must do it this way you can use dynamic sql (there are plenty of tutorials out there), but its highly recommended not to do it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Please change the body of the stored procedure as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE callProcedure
    (@newTable varchar(100),
     @tableField varchar(8000),
     @table varchar(100))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @query = 'DELETE FROM ' + @newTable + ';';

    SET @query += 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @newTable + ' ON;';

    SET @query += 'INSERT INTO ' + @newTable + '(' + @tableField + ') SELECT ' + @tableField + ' FROM ' + @table + ';';

    SET @query += 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @newTable + ' OFF;';

    EXEC (@query)
END
```